# Appcelerator app, iOS reviewer rejected app build for issue not present in the Simulator

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, titanium, appcelerator

I have an iOS app (built/distributed in Appcelerator Studio using the Titanium SDK) that has no issues in the Simulator but some functionality fails whenever an iOS reviewer reviews the app and it continues to get rejected. The function in question opens links from a web-view outside of the app in Safari. The reviewer's version of the app just opens the links within the app and this causes the app to be rejected because one of the links is a "donation" link.

Here is the basic function:

```
webview1.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
var url = webview1.getUrl();
var index = url.indexOf("goto");
var gotourl = url.substring(index+5);
Titanium.Platform.openURL(gotourl); }, false);
```

This has worked in the previously submitted build of the app but it has been many years now since that one was submitted. I have tried multiple version of the Titanium SDK (9.3.1.GA and 9.2.2.GA) with the same result (but I can't remember which version of the SDK I originally used).

Any help on how to make the submitted build act like the simulated build be appreciated.

Note: I am working on getting some of my coworkers to test the app using iTunes Connect Test Flight now, I just don't personally use an iPhone/iPad so that's why I rely on the Simulator for testing.

Thank you.

Comment: the last "false" parameter confuses me a bit. `addEventlistener` doesn't need that. So when your webview is loaded there is a link with http attached as a GET parameter,right? And you don#t have to click anything. That should be fine with your code. `Ti.Platform.openURL()` works fine on iOS with external links. Also "opens within the app" would only be possible if you are setting the webview1.url or click the link inside the webview. If you open an external link from your app there will be a back button with your app name in the top left Safari corner. But that is outside your app then.

Comment: So maybe they want you to use `SFSafariViewController` https://github.com/appcelerator-modules/titanium-web-dialog ? Or is just the donation link in general the problem?

Answer (score 2):

@miga Thank you for looking over my question and helping! After further review, I found the issue: the reviewer was always using an iPad and I was always testing on an iPhone. I'm using the Mobile Detect script (http://mobiledetect.net/) to detect if it's an iOS device or an Android to deliver the links differently (since both versions use the same code base). The latest version of the iPad (8th generation) in the Simulator isn't detected as iOS (but the iPhone in the Simulator is). I adjusted my detect code to account for this and now everything should be fine - I just re-submitted it for review.

Comment: ah, ok :) They always use iPads (not sure why). Glad you've found the issue!